# Non static method in static factory for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, static, fragment

I am constructing a fragment using the following way:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public MyFragment() {    }

    public static final myFragment newInstance(String string) {
        myFragment fragment = new myFragment ();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(string); 
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

I'd like to get a variable from resources in `newInstance`, but `getResources()` is not static.

Is there any other way to access it, except for passing it as an argument to `newInstance()`?

Comment: Why do you want to access your resources in `newInstance()`? A `newInstance()` method for a Fragment is generally to pass arguments into the Fragment as you are doing. The work that involves resources usually comes when the Fragment is actually being inflated or shown on screen during the Fragment lifecycle methods.

Comment: @Tanis.7x What I put in the bundle depends on a value that I have in my resources, so I would like to read it and have a condition there, but I guess you are right; my design is probably flawed.